# Create an array list in java and store values tied to an employee name

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program that calculates an employees annual salary based upon there base salary and commission sales.  I want to take the program a step further and create an arrayList that will ask for the employee name and then create an array, store the values from the program and print out those values for each employee name inputted.

I imagine that I need to create a for or a else loop to collect the data.  Problem is I'm not sure where to do that and how to create the array. I have two classes:

1 class for my commission variable's and calculations:

```
package Commissions;

public class Calculations {

    double totalSales;
    private double comRate = 0.025;
    private double annualSal = 80000;
    private double salesTarget = 120000;
    private double acceleration = 0.015;
    private double compensation;

    public Calculations (double TotalSales) {
        this.totalSales = totalSales;

    }

    public double getCommissionCalc () {

        if (totalSales >= salesTarget) {

            compensation = (annualSal + (totalSales * (comRate + acceleration)));
                return compensation;

        } else if (totalSales >= salesTarget * .8) {

            compensation = (annualSal + (totalSales * comRate));
                return compensation;

        } else {

            compensation = annualSal;
                return compensation;
        }
    }

}
```

1 class for my main and user input

```
package Commissions;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class paycheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        System.out.println("Enter the employee name: ");
        long empName = input.nextLong();

        mediaArray[empName];

        System.out.println("Enter your total sales for the year:  ");
        double totalSales = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("\r");

        Calculations c = new Calculations (totalSales);

        System.out.println("Your Total compensation with your annual sales is:  " + nf.format(c.getCommissionCalc()));

        System.out.println("\r");

        System.out.println("If you were to increase your sales you could earn even more money!");

        System.out.println("\r");

        double i = totalSales + 5000;
        double finish = totalSales * 1.5;

        while (i <= finish) {

            c.totalSales = i;

            System.out.println("If you were to increase your sales commission to " + nf.format(i) + " you could earn: " + nf.format(c.getCommissionCalc()));

            i = i + 5000;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: You need to have a while loop where user keep entering values.

Comment: The example is this with current code:   Enter your total sales for the year:  120000  Your Total compensation with your annual sales is:  $80,000.00,  If you were to increase your sales commission to $125,000.00 you could earn: $85,000.00,  If you were to increase your sales commission to $130,000.00 you could earn: $85,200.00

Comment: what I would like it to do is add the following:  Please enter the employee name:  David   ,  David please enter your total sales:  120000, Your annual salary.......(then it completes the existing while loop),  I need to add a second while loop that asks:  How many employees have commission sales?  Then repeat the loop that many times.  I'm just learning loops and arrays so I'm not sure how to construct my new while loop while using the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code as per my understanding of your problem, had to correct few things as you are saying enter name but taking long as input:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paycheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        while (true) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            System.out.println("Enter the employee name (enter exit to exit): ");
            String empName = input.nextLine();
            // mediaArray[empName];

            if(empName.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter your total sales for the year:  ");
            double totalSales = input.nextDouble();

            Calculations c = new Calculations(totalSales);

            System.out
                    .println("Your Total compensation with your annual sales is:  "
                            + nf.format(c.getCommissionCalc()));

            System.out.println("\r");

            System.out
                    .println("If you were to increase your sales you could earn even more money!");

            System.out.println("\r");
            double i = totalSales + 5000;
            double finish = totalSales * 1.5;

            while (i <= finish) {

                c.totalSales = i;

                System.out
                        .println("If you were to increase your sales commission to "
                                + nf.format(i)
                                + " you could earn: "
                                + nf.format(c.getCommissionCalc()));

                i = i + 5000;
            }
            System.out.println("\r");

            //store employee data into arraylist
            empList.add(new Employee(empName, i));
        }


        for(Employee emp : empList) {
            System.out.println("Employee Name: " + emp.getName() + " Total Sales: " + emp.getSales());
        }
    }
}

class Employee {

    private String name;
    private Double sales;

    public Employee(String empName, double totalSales) {
        this.name = empName;
        this.sales = totalSales;
    }

    public Double getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    public void setSales(Double sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense now and i can see what i was missing.  One question I have is i'm now trying to compare the employees in the array and find out who had the highest sales.  I wrote this code but it doesn't like the variable type because:  Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getSales() in the type Employee is not applicable for the arguments (int)                        This is my code too compare the values,  if(emp.getSales(1) < emp.getSales(2))  System.out.println(emp.getSales(2) + "Earned more than " + emp.getSales(1));